# How to write R output to Xlsx?

Tags: r

i want use the Example Data of following homepage

https://github.com/pour-aboughadareh/Stabilitysoft

and R Code to get the output as excel.

Can anyone help me to write the result$statistic as an xlsx Output.

```
results <- Calculate(df)
 print(results$statistics)

d <- results$statistics

write.xlsx(d,file="C:\ausgabea.xlsx", colNames = TRUE)
```

I use the example1 .

But it does not work

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean that your current code does not work?  Do you get an error message?  Did you remember to include `library(xlsx)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

library(writexl);
write_xlsx(d,"ausgabea.xlsx")

You don't need to specify "col_names = TRUE" because it is already the default. The file will be saved to your working directory. You can find out where your working directory is using:

getwd()

Answer (score 0):

You can write it to `.csv` which works well with excel

```
write.table(d,file="C:\ausgabea.csv")
```